# React Router Bootstrap and Navbar redirection

Tags: react-router, navbar, react-bootstrap

I read so much today and yesterday and I am totally stuck in my development. In order to learn React.Js, I am making a simple website that displays pictures and description by categories. The problem I am facing is the link between my NavItems (of the navbar) and the redirections.

I have this router in my index.js:

```
render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRedirect to="/index" />
        <Route path="/index" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/dogs" component={Dogs}/>
        <Route path="/cats" component={Cats}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Navbar.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { 
    Navbar as BoostrapNavBar,
    Nav,
    NavItem,
    MenuItem,
    NavDropdown,
    Jumbotron, 
    Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';

export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <BoostrapNavBar inverse collapseOnSelect>
                <BoostrapNavBar.Header>
                    <BoostrapNavBar.Brand>
                        <a href="#">{this.props.navbar_title}</a>
                    </BoostrapNavBar.Brand>
                    <BoostrapNavBar.Toggle />
                </BoostrapNavBar.Header>
                <BoostrapNavBar.Collapse>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                        <NavItem href="/dogs">Dogs</NavItem> 
                        <NavItem href="/cats">Cats</NavItem> 
                    </Nav> 
                </BoostrapNavBar.Collapse>
            </BoostrapNavBar>
        );
    }
}
```

So my site render but, if I click one of my navitems, then a message will appear: `Cannot GET /dogs`.

So, I began to search on the internet about how does navbar works with react-router and... I got so many answers, but I can't make it work, I don't get why. I tried `LinkContainer` but something is wrong with history, so I check my `Router` in index.js without any success.

I read some articles about `<Switch>`, `<Browser>`, etc, but same, no success :( any idea?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do something like this?

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavBar, Nav, NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

...

```
<Nav>
    <NavItem componentClass={Link} href="/dogs" to="/dogs" active={location.pathname === '/dogs'}>Dogs</NavItem>
    <NavItem componentClass={Link} href="/cats" to="/cats" active={location.pathname === '/cats'}>Cats</NavItem>
</Nav>
```

Gotten from [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4463)

Comment: Ok, please explain your answer, I can't believe you make it work ! thank you

Comment: Sure. `componentClass` is setting a custom element for the `NavItem`, meaning you decide which component to render there. The `href` says which url to navigate to. `active` says that this `NavItem` is the active one when it matches a certain url, e.g., '/dogs'

Comment: The long term solution here, however, seems to be to use this npm package as well which marries `react-router` and `react-bootstrap` for you: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap

Comment: Thank you, I got it :) I tried `react-router-bootstrap` but with no success